# Firebase assigning enumerated limited data

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

So I am creating a simple game that each player will be assigned to a role.

So for example, here are the roles:

```
[rock, paper, scissors, scissors, rock]
```

The thing is the roles are limited and once assigned, there would be one less of that role.

How do I do these kind of calculations in Firebase. My initial thought would be,

Try to query back and forth, if the number of the roles has been exhausted, try another in the frontend and fire up another request. But doing such will place network burden.

What are your thoughts on achieving this.

Comment: This doesn't sound like a calculation that would be native to Firebase products.  It sounds like you're just going to have to write the code that expresses the logic of your game using the database as a store for your game state.

Comment: You won't be able to know how many of the roles have been take if the game needs to simultaneously assign roles on the start of the game.

Comment: This sounds feasible: each client runs a transaction on the `roles` node, where security rules ensure that the state transition is legal. Your rules will become length, since rules can't count the number of children, but it should be possible. The game itself would typically either run as an administrative process, or you could allow a reset of the available roles in your security rules.

Comment: I'm not sure what this specifically has to do with Cloud Functions btw. If you do it there, it's a lot more conventional. Your code there would take the user's request, validate it, and then update the database with a transaction.